# Calculating n! in x86 assembly without using multiplication?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I am trying to calculate n! in x86 assembly without using multiplication (i know it's dumb but it tests my ability to store and manipulate data in registers). I am told you can do this with not too many lines of assembly.

I know that n! = n * (n-1)! so if i need to calculate 5! i can add 4! 5 times (5! = 4! + 4! + 4! + 4! + 4!). From there i just need to calculate 4! the same way all the way down to 2! = 1! + 1! and 1! = 1.

My first thought is to use a loop as such

```
mov eax, 0 ; clear eax
mov ecx, n ; because ecx is the loop counter
next:
    add eax, (n-1)! ; illegal 
loop next
```

I am assuming assembly will not let you do a recursive call in a loop like

```
next:
   dec edx ; decrement
   add eax, call nfact;
loop next
```

Where edx stores the number to take the factorial of.

I am just confused on how to properly do nested loops in such a way not to destroy any data i need and still get the result.

EDIT:

Here is how i calculate multiplication with repeated addition:

```
;calulate A*B

mov eax, a ;
mov ecx, b ;
mov ebx, 0 ; this will store a*b
next:
add ebx, eax;
loop next ; ecx is the loop counter that the loop instruction decrements

;;now ebx has the value a*b;
```

Comment: You can remember data a few different ways: (1) in registers, (2) in static memory locations (using the `db`, `dw`, `dd`, etc, assembly directives, or (3) on the stack (using `push` and `pop`).

Comment: my friend also told me he did this without needed data variables. so he only used registers which really makes me think how he did it.

Comment: Worst! Artificial! Restriction! Ever! :-)

Comment: Two different problems. One is solving factorial (possibly with recursion) and the other is using repeated addition as multiplication.  Tip solve them one at a time...

Comment: If you think about it, you don't really need that much. You probably need a couple of counters and a couple of accumulators. That's only four values you have more registers than that you can work with.

Comment: i can do multiplication as repeated addition, i will update original post with that data.
   
EDIT: Updated, the problem i am having to is how to loop that in a way to find n!

Comment: I think my problem is i am trying to calculate n! downward from n to 1, maybe i should build it upwards?

Comment: easy, n! = 1*2*...*n, so just use 2 loops, 1 for counting from 1 to n, 1 for multiplying

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Do `cmp edx,MAX` and `ja .tooLarge`; where MAX is the largest value of n where n! fits in 32-bits

Step 2: Do `mov eax,[lookupTable + edx * 4]`

That's 3 instructions. The lookup table won't be very big at all, and can be easily precomputed and stored as data (e.g. `lookupTables  dd 0,1,2,...`)

Comment: the idea is that we dont need a lookup table, no data variables are necessary.